# Merge First Row with the second row of column C if columns A & B are null only

Tags: python, dataframe

Need to Merge the second row values with the first row of column C if the rows in columns A&B are null only. If the continuous 2rows are not null then skip it

DATA:

```
   A        B       C
12525    1FWE23   1H654D
                  14654        
24798    14654    S56E82
65116    63546    38945        
46456    46485    R68R45
                  AD545    
A5D66    45346    QA6683
```

EXPECTED:

```
   A        B       C
12525    1FWE23   1H654D 14654       
                   
24798    14654    S56E82
65116    63546    38945
46456    46485    R68R45 AD545    
                  
A5D66    45346    QA6683
```

Tried this code -

```
df2.loc[df2['A'] != '', 'C'] = df2["C"] + ' ' + df2["C"].shift(-1).fillna("")
```

But it doesn't work if we have continuous 2rows with values.

My code result.

```
   A        B       C
12525    1FWE23   1H654D 14654       
                   
24798    14654    S56E82 38945
65116    63546    38945 R68R45 
46456    46485    R68R45 AD545    
                  
A5D66    45346    QA6683
```

Comment: Tried this code - "df2.loc[df2['A'] != '', 'C'] = df2["C"] + ' ' + df2["C"].shift(-1).fillna("")". But it doesn't work if we have continuous 2rows with values.

Comment: Please edit your question to include your code (the one from your comment), and examples with input, output or error, desired output...

Comment: @Swifty, Updated the question with my code and the output I got

Answer (score 0):

Assumption: the empty values under A and B are null
and A & B are unique

```
# ffill the null values
# groupby and aggregate

out=df.ffill().groupby(['A','B'], as_index=False)['C'].agg(' '.join)
out
```

```
        A        B  C
0   12525   1FWE23  1H654D 14654
1   24798    14654  S56E82
2   46456    46485  R68R45 AD545
3   65116    63546  38945
4   A5D66    45346  QA6683
```

Comment: I tried ur code, but didn't solved the issue

Comment: can you elaborate on it please? @Pravin, why it failed, when it matched the expected output

Comment: The code groupby all the nulls of column A and takes its values from column C and joins together in a single row. For example from the above mentioned table, I'm getting the values as "14654 AD545" in a single row

Comment: oh! you need to create a separate column ?

Comment: No, I just need to merge the values of column C which are null in column A with its previous rows.

Comment: yes! that is exactly what I have done. to use groupby i ffill A and B and then combine the C. unless you only want to check A for null